# Howto access a namespace with the same name as a class instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a question regarding namespace names and classes:

If I have a class called cVeloConnect in namespace VeloConnect.
e.g.

```
namespace VeloConnect
{
    public class cVeloConnect
    {
        // Some content
        public void PrintMe();

    }

    public class cSomeClass
    {
        // Some content

    }
}
```

And now I want to create a new instance of cVeloConnect, calling this instance VeloConnect, I cannot access the VeloConnect namespace anymore...
e.g

```
VeloConnect.cVeloConnect VeloConnect = new VeloConnect.cVeloConnect();
VeloConnect.PrintMe();
// The below thing is not possible
VeloConnect.cSomeClass MyClass = new VeloConnect.cSomeClass();
```

How can I access the other class, if I don't want to rename the namespace or my previous instance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one option is to follow naming conventions to avoid this sort of thing - your classes *shouldn't* start with `c`, and your local variables would normally start with a lower case letter.

To avoid having to use the namespace *at all* in the declaration, you can just use a `using` directive at the top of your code. Or if you *really* want to specify the namespace, you could use `global::`:

```
global::VeloConnect.cSomeClass MyClass = new global::VeloConnect.cSomeClass();
```

In general though, I don't like seeing namespaces within my actual code - I prefer having `using` directives so I can just use the simple names in the body of the code. Either way, I would *strongly* urge you to start following the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Alias the namespace;

```
 using vc=VeloConnect;

 // ... then, later ....

 vc.cVeloConnect VeloConnect = new vc.cVeloConnect();
 VeloConnect.PrintMe();
 // The below thing is not possible
 vc.cSomeClass MyClass = new vc.cSomeClass();
```